# Animate certain elements out on page change

Tags: jquery, animation

So I have been reading into page transitions and they get very complex very quickly. I am still new to jQuery so I was hoping to get a simplified answer as to how to execute animations (namely on individual elements) on page transitions.

*I apologise for how basic these questions are but as I am sure you all know, once you grasp the basic fundamentals and their simplistic concepts it makes the rest a whole lot easier.*

So from what I have read, you would use jQuery to detect the page change, execute the animation then allow for the change of page.

Then jQuery would execute on page load and animate the elements in.

**Question 1:**
So for the first part, I have figured out that I would need to use:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  return "Handler for .unload() called.";
});
```

How would I use this to delay the change of page long enough to complete my animations, and would this account for page changes using the back and forward browser buttons?

**Question 2:**
How would I make sure my elements start off screen when the new page is loading and only animate in once the content has been loaded?

The $(document).ready function will only execute once the page is ready and thus will show the logo on screen and the jump it off screen and animate it back on.

P.s I will update this thread with detailed steps on how I get to my desired result once I figure it all out. Massive thanks.

Comment: The simplest solution I can give you for **Question 2** would be to use a JS Script. [WOW.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to figure out a basic understanding of how to do this without using a prebuilt script. Basically, I want to figure out how to delay the page change so I can animate elements out, then delay the new page load so I can animate elements in (once the page content has fully loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you can try out the following jquery code.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".animation").fadeOut("slow").delay(1000);
});
```

The above animation will load as soon as the page is loaded. You can also add `.delay()` if you would like to add an additional delay :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide animations for page changes within one site - you probably planning to make something what is called "one page application".

If that is your goal I think you really should start from here:
https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/The-State-of-the-HTML5-History-API

Then answer to your Question1 would be:
- Use ajax and History API instead

Answer for Question2:
- You never leave the page actually. Using ajaxy loader you changing the content (with animations when you hide previous page content and when you show the new page content), and then you pushing a new history state to make it possible for user to navigate with the browser buttons.
PS. You can achieve some nice looking effects leaving the repeated part of the content in place (eg. logo image) and animate only the rest of the content.

Alternatively - have a look [here](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js?files=1) For some other solution (might be easier to start with):
https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js?files=1
to achieve something like [this](https://rawgit.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js/master/demos/csstricks/index.html) or like [this](https://rawgit.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js/master/demos/anchor-transitions/index.html)

Comment: It would be the transitions between multiple pages, slingle page applications are fine, I am struggling more with the default page transitions. So if I click a nav link the browser loads the next page instantly... want to figure out how to delay the page change so I can animate elements, then delay the new page load so I can animate elements in

Comment: @SonyThePony - well, if you matched the other ansewer as correct, i think we have nothing to talk about. ..

Comment: @SonyThePony - you can NOT delay page change, (with 1 exception which is displaying alert or confirm dialog), what you can do is to take over the navigation click handlers and add your desired behaviour before you navigate - but you will NEVER handle back/forward buttons unless you make ONE PAGE APP. ...ok ...i already feel like a fool i spent so much time on this - for nothing. cheers and good luck.